# Comparing dates in VBA Variables

Tags: vba, date, variant

I have encountered an interesting problem with the codes. I am trying to find a max value ( a date ) between 3 variants, but it doesn't work quite good.

Here is the codes;

```
If CountValues(WA1, WA2, WA3) <> CountValues(WS_1, WS_2, WS3) Then

    MAX_DATE = ""
        Else

If WA1 = "" Then
WA1 = "01.01.1990"
End If
If WA2 = "" Then
WA2 = "01.01.1990"
End If
If WA3 = "" Then
WA3 = "01.01.1990"
End If
            If WA1 >= WA2 And WA1 >= WA3 Then
                MAX_DATE = WA1
            Else
                If WA2 >= WA3 And WA2 >= WA1 Then
                    MAX_DATE = WA2
                Else
                    If WA3 >= WA2 And WA3 >= WA1 Then
                        MAX_DATE = WA3



End If
End If
End If
End If
```

Right now WA1 is equal to 13.11.2017 and WA2 and WA3 is empty. And WS_1 has a value but others don't, so the first check is working. They are shown as " WA2 = "" " in the F8 check. But still, MAX_DATE says that second If function is true, so it goes to the WA2 which is nothing, but it should give the WA1 value.

Any idea to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to comparison method. Empty string is "less" then any string. Try the following solution:

Assign some values to these variables, so program can compare it, don't leave it empty. Use some default value (e.g. very old date, which wouldn't alter the maximum, like `1900-01-01`). And, as I said yesterday in response to the same question of yours, use `Date` type, so program knows how to compare it. If you'll store dates as `Variants` comparison can return wrong result (you pass strings to these variables, so program will apply string comparison, if they're `Variant` and will compare them as dates, if they're stored as `Date`).

Also, determining maximum value could be little bit simplier:

```
MAX_DATE = WA3
If WA1 > WA2 Then
    If WA1 > WA3 Then MAX_DATE = WA1
Else
    If WA2 > WA3 Then MAX_DATE = WA2
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your info, and I changed the codes a little bit. I gave them a min. value, but this time the macro chosen the WA3, which is 01.01.1990. I edited the codes in the question.

Comment: You almost got it right. You need to declare `WA1`, etc. as `Date` variables :) Straight after delcaring them, assign this default value, to avoid check for emptiness (empty string can't be assigned to `Date` variable) or everywhere where you assign this empty string, change it to default date.

Comment: But if I skip the check the emptiness part ( because of declaring them as date ), how can I declare the MAX_DATE value as "" if the value counts are not match?

Comment: Easy. Now, check if the value is equal to 1900-01-01 - it would mean that it hasn't been affected and is not set. This way you'll get desired result.